# How to find Start and End IP address for CIDR input in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4, postgresql-9.2, postgresql-9.5, cidr

I have CIDR input as **10.0.0.0/28**
How can i find Start and End IP address in that input.
Manually i understood that **10.0.0.0** is start address
and **10.0.0.15** is End IP, Is there any way in PostgreSQL to find that?

Comment: `10.0.0.10/28` is a wrong CIDR

Comment: Thank you @AkhileshMishra, I wanted to know we can notate 10.0.0.10/28 for 10.0.0.0/28 Right? So First i need to validate the user enters right Notation and then i need to return First IP and Last IP Address in the CIDR.

Comment: If you want to take input as `10.0.0.10/28` then it will be as `inet`. then you can get the values. I have added both of the versions in the answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In you question `10.0.0.10/28` is a wrong CIDR Input. It should be `10.0.0.0/28`
You can write your query like this:

```
select 
host('10.0.0.0/28'::cidr) AS lower,
host(broadcast('10.0.0.0/28'::cidr)) AS upper
```

**Updated Answer** - if Input is as `inet` then try this way

```
select 
host(network('10.0.0.10/28'::inet)) AS lower,
host(broadcast(network('10.0.0.10/28'::inet)::cidr)) AS upper
```

[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.5&fiddle=d296c2bb83fc4eadd6a8c2f2bd5bf18c)